# Clearing a text field using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function clear() {
    document.getElementById('box').value = " ";
    };
</script>

<input type="text" id="box" onFocus="clear()" value="Type name here">
```

Hi, so i'm fairly new to javascript and I'm trying to clear a text field onFocus. I have searched the site and found other ways to do this, but i was curious as to why this code wouldn't work. Would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Comment: That was it, thank you! cannot use clear(), typed in something else and its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern day browsers have it built it in. It is the placeholder attribute. No JavaScript is needed.

```html
<input type="text" id="box" placeholder="Type name here">
```

Reason your code did not run was a name collision with `document.clear` which is deprecated, if you change the name it works fine.

```js
function xclear() { 
    document.getElementById('box').value = " ";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" onFocus="xclear()" value="Type name here">
```

Comment: Thanks yes that is a solution to the problem, but i was really trying to understand why the code wouldn't work. the input has a 'value', and the javascript should change that value but it doesn't..